# How to calculate flight duration from given datetime and timezone?

Tags: timezone, momentjs

i have problems getting the right time difference for a given route and a departing and arrival time plus the timezones.

My route is Vienna to Washington D.C. Departing time from Vienna is 10.09.2014 10:25 (vienna time) and arrival time is 10.09.2014 14:20 (washington time)
The timezone for both are Europe/Vienna and US/Eastern.

I use momentjs + momentjs/timezone to get the right values. But momentjs is returning the wrong value in minutes.

The correct value should be 595 Minutes makes 9h 55m.

This is the line i tried:

```
moment( '10.09.2014 1420', 'DD.MM.YYYY HHmm').tz( 'US/Eastern').diff( moment( '10.09.2014 1025', 'DD.MM.YYYY HHmm').tz( 'Europe/Vienna'), 'minutes');
```

I tried even with moment.tz( date, format, timezone).diff( ...) but this returns 235 too.

Why it returns 235 ?
You can easily test this on the momentjs.com/timezone site by using the console in your webdev toolbar.

What am i doing wrong here? Both times i have are always local airport time, and i want the time difference in minutes.

Comment: have you tried: `moment.tz('10.09.2014 1025', 'DD.MM.YYYY HHmm', 'Europe/Vienna')` (interpret input time string as time in Vienna)?

Comment: as i wrote right after the command line, i even tried with moment.tz. doesnt work. same result.

Comment: try it. It returns the correct `595`: `moment.tz( '10.09.2014 1420', 'DD.MM.YYYY HHmm', 'US/Eastern').diff( moment.tz( '10.09.2014 1025', 'DD.MM.YYYY HHmm', 'Europe/Vienna'), 'minutes');`

Comment: it is the difference between: "parse string, interpret it as X timezone, convert to Y timezone" and "parse string, interpret it as Y timezone"

Comment: arhg. on momentjs now it returns 595. its version 0.2.2 i have 0.1.0

Comment: You probably didn't have the time zone data and thus got the local time.  This was [fixed in moment-timezone 0.2.0](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/106).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question.

The timezone data was missing. Be careful when using and building momentjs. Check that you are building including timezone data.

In my case i had to use a specific set of languages too. So i had a custom grunt call in order to build.

Now it works.